# How to estimate 2D similarity transformation (linear conformal, nonreflective similarity) in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, affinetransform, homography

I'm trying to search a specific object in input images by matching SIFT descriptors and finding the transformation matrix by RANSAC. The object can only be modified in scene by similarity transform in 2D space (scaled, rotated, translated), so I need to estimate 2x2 transform matrix instead of 3x3 homography matrix in 3D space. How can I achieve this in OpenCV?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=estimaterigidtransform#Mat%20estimateRigidTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20dst,%20bool%20fullAffine%29) (I do not know whether it is RANSAC, the code at http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/2.4.4/entry/modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp says RANSAC in its comment), the third parameter is set to `false` in order to get just scale+rotation+translation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> p1s,p2s;

    p1s.push_back(cv::Point2f( 1, 0));
    p1s.push_back(cv::Point2f( 0, 1));
    p1s.push_back(cv::Point2f(-1, 0));
    p1s.push_back(cv::Point2f( 0,-1));

    p2s.push_back(cv::Point2f(1+sqrt(2)/2, 1+sqrt(2)/2));
    p2s.push_back(cv::Point2f(1-sqrt(2)/2, 1+sqrt(2)/2));
    p2s.push_back(cv::Point2f(1-sqrt(2)/2, 1-sqrt(2)/2));
    p2s.push_back(cv::Point2f(1+sqrt(2)/2, 1-sqrt(2)/2));

    cv::Mat t = cv::estimateRigidTransform(p1s,p2s,false);

    std::cout << t << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

compiled and tested with OpenCV 2.4.4.
The output is:

```
[0.7071067988872528, -0.7071067988872528, 1.000000029802322;
  0.7071067988872528, 0.7071067988872528, 1.000000029802322]
```

Comment: This function needs an equal amount of points from each of the two images. I guess it's not suitable for a large number of outliers.

Comment: @lizarisk Yes. function doesn't even give output when there are large number of outliers

Answer (score 2):

You can use find an affine transformation between the point sets using opencv, this is slightly more general than the case you are describing (known as a similarity transform) as it  describes shearing transformations of the shapes as well.

It can be performed using the function `getAffineTransform(InputArray src, InputArray dst)`. This takes 2 sets of three points and calculates an affine transform between them.

Comment: This method is not robust, it's not directly applicable to many pairs of points containing outliers. Perhaps I should implement RANSAC on top of it by myself.

Comment: @lizarisk Yes, I think you could do this yourself. Out of interest, what are you using to match SIFT descriptors?

Comment: I'm trying BFMatcher with L2 norm and cross-checking and FlannBasedMatcher.

Comment: try estimateAffine3D() function.

Comment: Although the method getAffineTransform() is not robust enough for your application, if it is (more than) fast enough, you can derive a more robust algorithm. For example you could call it with multiple triples of points. Each call returns a matrix. Expectation is that most of the matrices are similar (to your expected result) with some outliers. You can calculate an element-wise arithmetic average for a first more robust, rough estimate. You can use this estimate to eliminate the outliers by calculating distance (min sum of sign x square) to your average and take the (non-element-wise) median.

Comment: "min sum of sign x square" is an attempt to sort the matrices before taking the median. Usually the optimal distance should be "minimal sum of squares", but you can't take a median from that kind of ordering. If there are problems, you can try to apply a threshold to determine outliers during the sorting.